# Trouble logging in to computer with my Ubuntu One account

Tags: login, ubuntu-one

I just bought an Ubuntu powered computer then recently created an Ubuntu One account on my phone which was successful. But when I try to log in on the computer it doesn't go through.

Comment: How did you create the account? Was it with some web service? Was the phone connected to the computer?

Comment: I created it online and yes on a wed service named Ubuntu 1. The phone wasn't connected to the computer!

Answer (score 2):

You've created an Ubuntu One account which is used for various sites and services related to Ubuntu.

According to the [Ubuntu One FAQ's](https://login.ubuntu.com/+faq#what-is-an-ubuntu-one-account)

> Q. What is an Ubuntu One account?
>
> Ubuntu One is now the single account you use to log in to all services and sites related to Ubuntu. Your Ubuntu One account is an email address and a password that you use to sign in to Ubuntu services.

This is not the login account you use to access your computer. That's completely local to the machine and must be set up by you on that machine. The first local administrative account is normally set up at installation time, and can be used to create further local accounts.

Comment: Can I get the administrators password maybe?

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu you would have set the admin password, which would just be the password on the first account you created. If it came pre-installed, the supplier should have given you the password, there's no default password within Ubuntu.